# Field extensions, stupid question

Tags: galois-theory, extension-field

I have just started to try and get my head around extensions, probably a lot of mistakes.

I am trying to solve a problem that goes like this :
$  f $ is an irreducible polynomial with rational coefficients, of degree $17$. And $\alpha$ a root. 
The were three parts to this exercise, first show that $ \alpha $ isn't rational, then compute the degree of  $\mathbb Q( \alpha)/ \mathbb Q$ and finally compute the degree of $\mathbb Q ( \alpha^2 + 17)/ \mathbb Q$. 
Now to prove the second point I used that f is separable (because $char(\mathbb Q)=0$ and $f$ irreducible) and therefore the extension $\mathbb Q (\alpha) / \mathbb Q$ has degree one.

My actual question arised in the third part. 
I feel like the following reasoning would be correct :
$\alpha^2 + 17$ is an element of $\mathbb Q (\alpha) / \mathbb Q$. Therefore $\mathbb Q( \alpha^2 + 17)/ \mathbb Q \subset \mathbb Q (\alpha) / \mathbb Q$. And because the degree of $\mathbb Q (\alpha) / \mathbb Q$ is $1$, $\mathbb Q( \alpha^2 + 17)/ \mathbb Q$  must also have degree one.

Now I feel like this must be BS since I never use that the polynomial has degree 17. But could someone tell me what I should point my nose at ?

Comment: This is hard to read.  [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is a good tutorial for formatting on this site.

Comment: Sorry about that, it's been a while since i've been here and was writing on my tablet. Had forgotten you can simply use the $ sign --'

Comment: The degree of $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)/\mathbb{Q}$ should equal $\deg f$...

Comment: If $\Bbb{Q}(\alpha)/\Bbb{Q}$ has degree $1$, then won't $\alpha$ be in $\Bbb{Q}$?

Comment: Does that imply that there are no possible intermediate field extensions ?

Comment: @Pastudent hint: $17$ is a prime.

Comment: Because it is prime and $f$ irreducible the degree of the splitting field is $17$, but since there is no prime factor decomposition,  you can't find intermediate field extensions. You take all the roots at once  ?

Comment: Why is the degree of $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha))/\mathbb{Q}=1$? Shouldn't it be $17$? Now, since $a^2+17 \in \mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$, the extension $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha^2+17)/\mathbb{Q}$ should be a divisor of $17$. Also, don't worry about that weird $17$, it just means ("the first random primer number I came out with"

Comment: @David Is the reason I gave in the comment just above yours correct ?

Comment: You are right, there are no (non-trivial) intermediate extensions, because the orders of the "step-by-step" extensions multiplied together should equal the order of the "direct" extension

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why is the degree of $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)/\mathbb{Q}=1$? Shouldn't it be $17$? If it were $1$ then $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha))=\mathbb{Q}$ and the exercise becomes quite simple.

Now, since $a^2+17 \in \mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$, the extension $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha^2+17)/\mathbb{Q}$ should be a divisor of $17$. I think you can conclude something from here

Also, don't worry about that weird $17$, it just means "the first random primer number I came out with"